# Anbox error after installation

Tags: error-handling

I have installed Anbox but when I type anbox session-manager I get
 "anbox session-manager
/snap/anbox/71/usr/bin/anbox: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-8.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, that is PulseAudio. Try updating PulseAudio.

```
    sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev
```

Comment: Not descriptive, but it's what is happening.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. Tried  sudo apt install libpulse0:i386
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio still doesn't work.

Comment: Does `pulseaudio` command do anything?

Comment: $ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.